# A question regarding multi variate functions

Tags: visualization

When we have a simple one variable function $y = f(x)$, $f(x)$ gives the height of function/curve at an arbitrary point $x$, but if we have a multivariate function $u = f(x,y)$, what does it give us?

Comment: It's simply still the height…

Comment: In the case of multivariate functions, you can think of the domain of the function ($(x,y)$ in this case) as a two-dimensional plane. Then the $u$-coordinate can be a height, sort of like a mountain or similar.

Comment: Similar to cross product between 2 vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Why not visiting [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/math/) and playing around with different functions $u(x,y)$?

[image: Example 1][image: Example 2]
[image: Example 3]